# IDA Python get struct type with dependencies

Tags: ida, python

Over the IDA Gui it is possible to export a structure with dependencies to a header file. For example if I export a struct that has one member from type DWORD than the header file also contains "typedef unsigned int DWORD".

I want to do a similar task with the python api.

```
def get_member_type(struct, idx):
   member = ida_struct.get_member(struct, idx)
   tif = tinfo_t()
   ida_struct.get_member_tinfo(member, tif)
   return tif
```

This function return the type of the struct members for example "DWORD" but how can I get the information that this is a unsigned int?

Comment: You can use the difference in size or offset value.

Comment: You're confusing things. You're asking about a local type but show example how you get a member of assembly structure, not a local type(there are 2 windows: Structures and Local Types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_decls(ordinals_sring, flags)` return a string with the same content as the "export to header file" option in the GUI.

The ordinals string can contain multiple ordinals seperated with a comma and all PDF_ Flags can be used (for example PDF_INCL_DEPS).

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me, it even delineates `int` from `int32_t`.

```
def get_member_typename(sid, offset):
    s = ida_struct.get_struc(sid)
    m = ida_struct.get_member(s, offset)
    tif = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()
    if ida_struct.get_member_tinfo(m, tif):
        return tif.__str__() 
    return ""
```